# How to Give Nav Items Automatically Computed Background Color

Tags: jquery, html, css

Lets say I have a navigation menu. And in that menu, links to pages (shocker right). I want the background color for each link to be different, but set via percentage between two defined colors.

For example, lets say I chose #000 and #fff as my colors. I want to say via SASS that the first items background color will always be #000, and the last items background color will always be #fff. However, depending on the number of items in the nav menu, the percentage will be pulled and that corresponding color stop will be used for the "between" items backgrounds.

Here's an illustration just in case I'm losing anyone:

The first color ramp represents 4 menu items. Each items position is equally divided from 100% and has a resulting color stop. That number becomes the background of said item.

The second color ramp represents 5 menu items. Everything else applies, but with calculations done for 5 items now.

[image]

My use for this comes with not wanting to manually type tons of :nth-child selectors. And if they add/remove items, those :nth color rules no longer apply. How would one do this with css and jQuery?

Comment: Adjusted OP to better ask the question as SCSS cannot access the DOM.

Comment: Thank you @rageandqq for that adjustment

Comment: Why not just have one gradient across the menu container and not have a background on any of the menu items?

Comment: @JesseKernaghan because each item is to have a solid background and not a gradient background. The gradient/color ramp is only used for computational purposes to pull the percentages corresponding solid color value.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, here is my try, i will try to comment the code as much as possible :D
let's say you have 4 divs in HTML :

```
<div data-color-start=#000" data-color-end="#fff" id="wrapper">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

then we need jQuery code to calculate the number of divs, calculate the background-colors which then will be added to our divs:

(before you dive in, this can be optimised)

```
// returns an array (so we can use easily in getColors)
function parseHex( hexCode ) {
    var returned;
    if( hexCode.length === '4' ) {
        returned[0] = parseInt( hexCode[1], 16 ); // transforsm in a normal number, lie you would use in rgb()
        returned[1] = parseInt( hexCode[2], 16 );
        returned[2] = parseInt( hexCode[3], 16 );
    }
    else {
        //i suppose this is the case like #012345
        returned[0] = parseInt( hexCode.substring( 1,3 ), 16 ); //same thing like above but we substring'ed the hexCode
        returned[1] = parseInt( hexCode.substring( 3,5 ), 16 );
        returned[2] = parseInt( hexCode.substring( 5 ), 16 );
    }

    return returned; // so we return the array
}


// gets the colors based on the parameters, returns array
function getColors( startColor, endColor, number ) {
    var startArr = parseHex( startColor );
    var endArr = parseHex( endColor );
    var ratioOne, ratioTwo, ratioThree;
    var i=0;
    var colors; // the returned array
    var temp; //used as temporary variable in for loop
    var one, two, three; // this will store bool values
    // let's say we have rgb(100,0,20) to rgb(10,200,10)
    // we have for RED to decrease the value of our gradient
    // for GREEN to increase it
    // for BLUE to decrease it
    one = startArr[0] < endArr[0]; //so true if we have to increase it
    two = startArr[1] < endArr[1];
    three = startArr[2] < endArr[2];

    // now basically we will find the ratio of each R, G, B, and make the gradient based on it
    ratioOne = Math.floor( (Math.abs( (startArr[0] - endArr[0] ) )+1) / (number-1) );
    ratioTwo = Math.floor( (Math.abs( (startArr[1] - endArr[1] ) )+1) / (number-1) );
    ratioThree = Math.floor( (Math.abs( (startArr[2] - endArr[2] ) )+1) / (number-1) );

    // store the first gradient
    colors[0] = 'rgba(' + startArr[0] + ',' + startArr[1] + ',' + startArr[2] + ')';
    for( i=1; i<(number-1); i+=1 ) {
        colors[i] = 'rgba(';
        if( one ) {
            temp = startArr[0] + ratioOne*i;
        }
        else {
            temp = startArr[0] - ratioOne*i;
        }
        colors[i] += temp;
        colors[i] += ',';

        if( two ) {
            temp = startArr[1] + ratioTwo*i;
        }
        else {
            temp = startArr[1] - ratioTwo*i;
        }
        // we modify the temp variable each time, so this is not a problem
        colors[i] += temp;
        colors[i] += ',';

        if( three ) {
            temp = startArr[2] + ratioThree*i;
        }
        else {
            temp = startArr[2] - ratioThree*i;
        }
        colors[i] += temp;
        colors[i] += ')';
    }

     // i will be just one more than the i which our for loop ended
    colors[i] = 'rgba(' + endArr[0] + ',' + endArr[1] + ',' + endArr[2] + ')';

    return colors; // we now have all the colors from our gradient
}

var wrapper = $('#wrapper'); // store this, will be used later
var startColor = wrapper.data('color-start'); // remember the HTML ?
var endColor = wrapper.data('color-end');
var elements = wrapper.find('.child'); // now store the links from the header
var elLength = elements.length; // get the number of links in the menu

var colors = getColors( startColor, endColor, elLength );

for( var i=0; i<elLength; i+=1 ) {
    elements[i].style('background-color', colors[i]);
}
```

so you store in html the first color and the last color, and then the js code appends inline style to every link/div/whatever the background color (via an rgb color). the gradient you showed us is done by a mathematical function (for example f(x) = x; or smth like that). that is why you can calculate the rgb color with `ratioOne`, `ratioTwo` and `ratioThree`

I hope i did not make any errors, and hope you get the idea. As you already know, this can not be done via SASS, only JS(becouse you want to write less code, eh?)

Answer (score 1):

First, I think this is best achieved with Javascript rather than through css or SASS.  I'm not too familiar with all of SASS's capabilities, but my understanding is that SASS is compiled into CSS at runtime, and therefore you wouldn't be able to dynamically update the list on the page.

With javascript you would be able to dynamically add or remove items from the list and have the colors update.

Okay, how to do it.
First, store the values as rgb colors, not Hex.  So in your example above, you would store 0,0,0 for black and 255, 255, 255 for white.

Then when you render the page, finding the intermediate values is as easy as counting the number of elements you have - thats the number of steps you need, and dividing the distance between each value pair, starting and ending r, g, and b.

Use background-color: rgba(x,x,x,1) to set your background colors, and you should be good to go.

Here's some quick and dirty javascript code that will calculate the steps for you

```
var startingRGB = [0,0,0];
var endingRGB = [255, 255, 255];
var steps = 5;

var eachStep = [
    (endingRGB[0] - startingRGB[0])/(steps-1),
    (endingRGB[1] - startingRGB[1])/(steps-1),
    (endingRGB[2] - startingRGB[2])/(steps-1)
];

var backgrounds = [];

for(var i = 0; i < steps; i++){
    backgrounds.push([
        Math.abs(startingRGB[0] + (eachStep[0] * i)),
        Math.abs(startingRGB[1] + (eachStep[1] * i)),
        Math.abs(startingRGB[2] + (eachStep[2] * i))
    ]);
}
```

Run this and backgrounds will have an array of rgb values for each step.

```
[0,0,0], [63.75,63.75,63.75], [127.5,127.5,127.5], [191.25,191.25,191.25],      
[255,255,255]
```